# Images centering in viewflipper

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, viewflipper

I have many ImageViews in ViewFlipper. Each ImageView has ScaleType set to FIT_START so images are "stick" to the top. Now I have problem with vertical images - they go to left, and I want to center them. I cant combine FIT_START and CENTER so I'm looking for another solution. Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
                iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                flipper.addView(
                        iv,
                        new          LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                (int)      Utils.dp2px(256,
                                        getApplicationContext())));


<ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:autoStart="false"
                android:flipInterval="0" >
</ViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your ImageView's width is set to `wrap_content`. You can try setting it to `fill_parent` instead

Comment: I added my code for creating view Flipper in xml and ImageView in code